# Retrieve last value of Stream when there are multiple values

Tags: flutter

I have a Stream that gets filled by listening to a TextField (that has a `searchController` attached):

```dart
streamController = StreamController<String>.broadcast();
searchController.addListener(() => streamController.sink.add(searchController.text));
```

I then send off a query to `longExpensiveSearch` on each result:

```dart
Stream<List<SearchResult>> get results =>
      streamController
          .stream
          .asyncMap((text) => longExpensiveSearch(query: text));
```

Finally, I have a `StreamBuilder` that displays the search results:

```dart
// inside build()
StreamBuilder<List<SearchResult>>(
      stream: widget.model.results,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
            ... 
      })
```

The `longExpensiveSearch` operation takes ~1 second to perform.

When a user types a search query in the text field (e.g. `banana`), a query is processed sequentially for every individual letter press:

```
longExpensiveSearch(query: "b")
longExpensiveSearch(query: "ba")
longExpensiveSearch(query: "ban")
longExpensiveSearch(query: "bana")
longExpensiveSearch(query: "banan")
longExpensiveSearch(query: "banana")
```

Is there a way to skip over the intermediate steps so that only the last query is performed?

This could be, for example, the stream detecting that "banana" is buffered while performing `longExpensiveSearch(query: "b")` and skipping over all of the other steps to perform just `longExpensiveSearch(query: "banana")`?

#### What I've Tried

**1. Reading stream length** before returning the results

```dart
Stream<List<SearchResult>> get results async {
    int inBuffer = await streamController.stream.length;
    if(inBuffer > 0)
        return Stream.fromFuture(streamController.stream.last);

    return streamController.stream.asyncMap((text) => longExpensiveSearch(query: text));
}
```

The stream `length` always returned 0, despite many letters entered (and later processed via `asyncMap`). Maybe I'm using it wrong?

**2. Debouncing the TextField input** was unpredictable, and sometimes resulted in the wrong query getting executed (`banan` instead of `banana`, as shown below):

```
longExpensiveSearch(query: "b")
longExpensiveSearch(query: "ba") // Blocked by debouncer
longExpensiveSearch(query: "ban") // Blocked by debouncer
longExpensiveSearch(query: "bana") // Blocked by debouncer
longExpensiveSearch(query: "banan") // <-- this gets shown
longExpensiveSearch(query: "banana") // ❌ Blocked by debouncer
```

Any ideas?

Comment: how do you "Debounce the TextField"? i used [Stream.debounce](https://pub.dev/documentation/stream_transform/latest/stream_transform/RateLimit/debounce.html) multiple times and it always worked fine

Comment: I used https://pub.dev/packages/easy_debounce -- wasn't aware of the native `Stream.debounce` method. I'll try that out, thanks

Comment: try: `TextField(onChanged: streamController.add)` and `Stream<List<SearchResult>> get results =>
streamController
.stream.debounce(Duration(milliseconds: 500)).asyncMap((text) => longExpensiveSearch(query: text));`

Comment: sure, your welcome, btw as you can see you dont need `searchController` but maybe you need it for other things...

Comment: Feel free to add as an answer so I can mark it as accepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @pskink for the answer. There's a native Flutter library that supports debouncing the Right Way™.

Just required prepending `.debounce(Duration(milliseconds: 500))` to `asyncMap`:

```dart
Stream<List<SearchResult>> get results =>
      streamController
          .stream
          .debounce(Duration(milliseconds: 500))
          .asyncMap((text) => longExpensiveSearch(query: text));
```